# Is there a good online mathematics curriculum for elementary through high school?

Tags: learning, math

My kids are very responsive to learning math.  I have a math background and they respond to my methods of teaching.  But so far I haven't been consistent in terms of frequency and content.  I'd like to follow some format so they learn things in the right order.  Is there a good online program or book that will provide proper order, examples, problem sets, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.khanacademy.org/ has a lot of resources. Practice problems, hints, how-to videos.

There is a [myriad](http://collegeopentextbooks.org/opentextbookcontent/open-textbooks-by-subject/math) of open source textbooks out there too. These are mostly college texts, but there are also some high school texts. There are a lot of homeschooling resources out there too.

Answer (score 0):

A math teacher friend of mine recommended Saxon or Singapore.  There are a ton of resources available for each.  Based on some research I'm going to go with Saxon.

Answer (score -1):

Try ALEKS.COM I've used it in class for a student that had trouble working cooperatively.
The program works in conjunction with a super computer to select work sets and refreshers.